# SQL Group by difficulties with nested select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I got a problem with a SELECT where I have to group by Mail, so that I can send the result via mail.

I have data like this:

```
-------------------------
ArtNr|Status|  Date       |Mail             |Comment
  2     20    22.01.16     test1@mail.com    comment1
  3     20    23.01.16     test3@mail.com    comment2
  26    20    19.01.16     test2@mail.com    comment3
  25    20    05.01.16     test1@mail.com    comment3
```

I need to group this by mail so that I can send the data to only the ones that are concerned by it.

This what I have till now:

```
SELECT ArtNr, [Status], Date, Mail, Comment
From dbmail
Group by Mail
```

But this obviously won't work because I have no aggregate in it. I can't sum/count or max this because I need both datasets but sent to only one mail-address.

It can be that I just won't see wood before the trees.

Comment: What is the result you need? Maybe just row_number() for the mail to get an indicator when it changes?

Comment: or use `Order By Mail`

Comment: I need ArtNr Status Date and Comment for everything regaarding one mail -adress

Comment: I don't understand. In your sample data you have multiple rows with the test1@mail.com entry. Do you need the most recent row (according to date)? How do you determine which row you need?

Comment: Yes, what is the criteria for your query? Do you want one row per address or do want all rows for one address, or?

Comment: I need all rows for one adress. Thought it would come out of my text sorry :/

Comment: where mail = 'test1@mail.com'.  The question is not clear.  I need both datasets but sent to only one mail-address.  Which email?  What is a dataset.  Fix the question.

Comment: It needs to be dynamic :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some pseudo-ish code...

1. Get a list of unique email addresses.
2. For each unique email address get the rows to send
3. Send your email

You get the idea :-)

```
DECLARE @emailAddress NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT [email] FROM [table] FOR READONLY
OPEN cur
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @emailAddress WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
        BEGIN
            SELECT [somestuff] FROM [table] WHERE email = @emailAddress

            SEND YOUR EMAIL ///



        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @emailAddress
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` only applies when you're trying to extract an aggregate from the data, which as you said you aren't.

How to best fulfil this requirement really depends on how your destination application will deal with the data. Options include -

- Filtering the data client-side using LINQ or similar to pull back a list of the distinct values for mail, then iterating through them selecting all records that match.
- Sorting the records by Mail in the query and making the code start a new mail if the mail doesn't match that for the previous record
- Adding a `ROW_NUMBER()` field with `PARTITION BY Mail` and starting a new mail whenever that shows 1.

There's many more options available; what's the right way depends on how you're ultimately going to use the data. But the answer for what you've said so far doesn't include a `GROUP BY` clause in your SQL.

Comment: Will try it with a ROW_NUMBER() and post if it worked thanks for the suggestion.